# appendChild with create element, removing temporary element created

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I am trying to append element using `appendChild` with JavaScript. I am creating a element `<p>` for that and appending child for its inner HTML. Is there any option to remove `<p>` and `</p>` after appending child? I do not want `<p>` tags at all. I am trying to use it as a temp container to make sure my `appendChild` works.

```
var z = document.createElement('p');
z.innerHTML = 'test satu dua tiga';
document.body.appendChild(z);
```

Edit: I am trying to append new html content to existing html content on some action with javascript. When I am trying to do that I face the below error. So I am taking a new element and assigning new html to that element and then doing a appendchild.

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: So you don’t want an element, you want a `Text` node.

Comment: Why not [`document.createTextNode(text)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) instead of creating an element that you don't want?

Comment: I have issue with my content as it is not a div and a string. This is resulting in Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' exception. That is the reason I am trying to add p and remove p after appending child.

Comment: What issue? What errors? Please [edit] your question to include enough information, and code, to allow us to reproduce, and understand, your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to  append a `textNode`

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello!'))
```

`textNode` is a special type of DOM Node, which contains only text and no markup.
Creating a *"temporary"* `p` element is unnecessary

Comment: can I create a blank text node?

Comment: By blank you mean without any text?

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to?

Comment: I want to create a blank node and append value to it.

Comment: What value do you want to append? I mean, what is the end purpose?

Comment: Still don't see how this does not work as a solution for you. You are appending plain text, right, not another piece of markup?

Comment: I am trying to append new html content to existing html content.

Comment: Can you please provide the real code? I mean, as far as I understand, you just provided "pseudocode", which, is, by the way, working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159425/discussion-between-kurkula-and-armen-vardanyan).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it worked for html content. I used firstElementChild to remove temporary element created.

```
var z = document.createElement('p');
z.innerHTML = 'test satu dua tiga';
document.body.appendChild(z.firstElementChild);
```